# I can't get my website to scroll vertically butter.js may have something to do with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, portfolio

I have my website that I am working on (https://bobacup.repl.co). I have my `hero` container, which is the main part of the page. I then have my projects container, but I can't scroll to that. This is the `body` CSS looks like, in addition the `projects` CSS

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--background-color);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div#projects {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

I tried to position it absolutely from the top 100%, with a width of the client (`100vw`) and the height of the client (`100vh`), I can't seem to scroll with it though which is frustrating. I do think that may have to do with it is something I incorporated called `butter.js`. Here is the code for it, I don't know if this has anything to do with it but do keep in mind that it is in a separate file called `butter.js`. This is the JS for it,

```
(function(root) {
  var Butter = function() {

    var self = this;

    this.defaults = {
      wrapperId: 'butter',
      wrapperDamper: 0.07,
      cancelOnTouch: false
    }

    this.validateOptions = function(ops) {
      for (var prop in ops) {
        if (self.defaults.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          Object.defineProperty(self.defaults, prop, { value: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ops, prop).value })
        }
      }
    }

    this.wrapperDamper;
    this.wrapperId;
    this.cancelOnTouch;
    this.wrapper;
    this.wrapperOffset = 0;
    this.animateId;
    this.resizing = false;
    this.active = false;
    this.wrapperHeight;
    this.bodyHeight;
  };

  Butter.prototype = {

    init: function(options) {
      if (options) {
        this.validateOptions(options);
      }

      this.active = true;
      this.resizing = false;
      this.wrapperDamper = this.defaults.wrapperDamper;
      this.wrapperId = this.defaults.wrapperId;
      this.cancelOnTouch = this.defaults.cancelOnTouch;

      this.wrapper = document.getElementById(this.wrapperId);
      this.wrapper.style.position = 'fixed';
      this.wrapper.style.width = '100%';

      this.wrapperHeight = this.wrapper.clientHeight;
      document.body.style.height = this.wrapperHeight + 'px';

      window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this));
      if (this.cancelOnTouch) {
        window.addEventListener('touchstart', this.cancel.bind(this));
      }
      this.wrapperOffset = 0.0;
      this.animateId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));

      // window.addEventListener('load', this.resize.bind(this));
    },

    wrapperUpdate: function() {
      var scrollY = (document.scrollingElement != undefined) ? document.scrollingElement.scrollTop : (document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0.0);
      this.wrapperOffset += (scrollY - this.wrapperOffset) * this.wrapperDamper;
      this.wrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,' + (-this.wrapperOffset.toFixed(2)) + 'px, 0)';
    },

    checkResize: function() {
      if (this.wrapperHeight != this.wrapper.clientHeight) {
        this.resize();
      }
    },

    resize: function() {
      var self = this;
      if (!self.resizing) {
        self.resizing = true;
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(self.animateId);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          self.wrapperHeight = self.wrapper.clientHeight;
          if (parseInt(document.body.style.height) != parseInt(self.wrapperHeight)) {
            document.body.style.height = self.wrapperHeight + 'px';
          }
          self.animateId = window.requestAnimationFrame(self.animate.bind(self));
          self.resizing = false;
        }, 150)
      }
    },

    animate: function() {
      this.checkResize();
      this.wrapperUpdate();
      this.animateId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    },

    cancel: function() {
      if (this.active) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.animateId);

        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
        window.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.cancel);
        this.wrapper.removeAttribute('style');
        document.body.removeAttribute('style');

        this.active = false;
        this.wrapper = "";
        this.wrapperOffset = 0;
        this.resizing = true;
        this.animateId = "";
      }
    },
  };

  root.butter = new Butter();

})(this);
```